How is the time complexity of a selection algorithm calculated?
For a selection problem, for example select $k$ smallest items from a list of unsorted array of real numbers, to assess the performance of a algorithm how is the time complexity calculated? Is it evaluated based on a specific value of $k$ or is it averaged
across all possible values of $k$? That is $k \in \mathbb{N}, 0\lt k \lt n$.
My currently understanding is that the complexity is calculated based on single value of $k$ but it may be unfortunate.
I've asked a related question here but the accepted answer doesn't explicitly point out this.

Establishing tight resource requirements bounds on problems means proving something about all possible algorithms, possibly for one single abstract machine model.

It depends on the algorithm, but some algorithms promise that the running time will be at most $O(n)$, regardless of the value of $k$.  Thus, this is a worst case over all $k$.  As a result, this running time bound can be applied for any specific value of $k$ you have in mind (it says that $O(n)$ time applies simultaneously for all $k$).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians.
I don't know of any algorithm whose running time is obtained by averaging over $k$.  Some algorithms are evaluated by averaging over all random choices made by the algorithm (all its internal coin tosses).

Thanks for your explanation. One more thing I want your help is about the output of the selection algorithm in case the requirement is to return a collection of $k$ smallest values instead of just the $k$th smallest value. In this case, does the output have to be sorted?

@KtStudent, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm defines the selection problem clearly

@KtStudent Sometimes yes, sometimes no. Ask the person who gave the task.
